# I cannot sync my facebook pages on ChatterOn. What could be the problem of this?

Tags: chat, messaging, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-chat

I am a beginner of using ChatterOn on creating chatbot integrated on facebook messenger. The problem is that I cannot sync my facebook pages and it keeps saying this error "#100 Tried Accessing non-existing fields (perms) on node type (UserAccountsEdgeData).

How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have figured this out already but Facebook deprecated the `perms` field when asking for a user's account permissions and replaced it with `tasks` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#page-tasks).

In your case ChatterOn probably have an updated version that supports this.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thank you very much Tama =)